# Ubuntu connecting to Ubuntu Hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless

I have two computers both with Ubuntu 16.04. On my desktop, I create an ad-hoc network called "UbuntuTest". I make the Wi-Fi security WEP 128-bit Passphrase. Then on my laptop, I try to connect to this hotspot "UbuntuTest" using the key but it won't connect. It will try for about a minute and then it will disconnect.

The wireless card on my desktop is RT3092 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R PCIe and on my laptop is Centrino Advanced-N 6235.

How can I fix this so I can connect my ubuntu laptop to a hotspot created by my ubuntu desktop?

I should also note that other devices can connect to the hotspot I create on my desktop (i.e. iPhone, Mac, and Windows)

Thanks!

EDIT:
I ran the script described on [WiFi not Working Information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos).

The output of the script is at the following link [script output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24371122/) (iwconfig is in the output, just search iwconfig). There are two networks shown in the output NetworkICanConnectTo (which is my usual home wifi) and NetworkICanNOTConnectTo (which is the wifi I create on my desktop).

EDIT 2:

I also tried connecting my laptop (and desktop) to a wifi created by a raspberry pi running raspbian Jessie lite and I still have the same problem. So to sum it up I'm having trouble connecting ubuntu to a network created by a linux machine.

Comment: The information missing is: Does it connect to other networks?

Comment: I think what @CelticWarrior means by "it" is your ubuntu laptop. Note that for trouble shooting networking further information will be required. Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information

Comment: Yes, my laptop can connect to other networks.  
I figured more information would be needed but I've been at a loss for where to start, so thank you for the link. I'll run this script and update my post with the output.

Comment: Please post the output of `iwconfig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem. The above solution was helpful but I was not trying to do a peer connection but trying to have a computer act as a router. To fix my problem on my laptop (the device trying to connect to the network) I set my IPv4 Settings to manual by the following:

1. Clicked network manager (top right) and selected edit connections.
2. I then selected the connection that wasn't working (in my case "UbuntuTest") and clicked edit.
3. Under Wi-Fi tab, I didn't change anything but my settings were SSID: "UbuntuTest", Mode: Client, and MTU: automatic.
4. Under the IPv4 Settings, I changed the Method to Manual and under address, I added my IP address 10.42.43.2, set the Netmask to 255.255.255.0, and left the Gateway blank.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to set your wifi interface to ad-hoc mode. Below are the instructions step by step to setup an ad-hoc network from [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc)

Linux to Linux peers

tested on 10.04 Netbook Remix using the Broadcom B43 proprietary driver. Broadcom STA did not work properly

1. Right-mouse click the NetworkManager icon (top right)
2. Select "Edit Connections"
3. Click the "Wireless" tab
4. Click "Add" to edit a new wireless connection
5. On the wireless dialogue give the connection a name, e.g "Mochudi".

   1. SSID: "Mochudi". The SSID will appear on the NetworkManager for your other
      Peers
   2. Mode: Ad Hoc
   3. BSSID: leave blank
   4. MAC Address: leave blank
   5. MTU: leave as automatic
6. Click "Apply"
7. Click "Close"

If fixed IP addresses are required edit the IPv4 Settings Tab before closing NetworkManager above:

...as above then...

6a. Click "IPv4 Settings Tab"

```
Select Method "Manual"
Under Addresses click Add
Type your Address: 10.42.43.1
Type the Netmask: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: leave blank or 0.0.0.0
```

6b. Click "Apply"

7. Click "Close"

**Do the above for each machine joining your fixed IP address Ad-Hoc network except assign a unique Address to each machine, so 10.42.43.1 becomes 10.42.43.2 for the second computer, 10.42.43.3 for the third, etc.**